# Install MDAC on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, visual-basic

I'm trying to install VB6 on Windows 10, I've successfully installed based on a tutorial site in portuguese [http://www.michaelrigo.com/2015/08/guia-definitivo-instalacao-operacao-vb6.html], and now when I open projects I have the following reference marked

MISSING: Microsoft Remote Data Object 2.0

[image: References Dialog (MISSINGS)]

Note: ADLibVB6 is a dll made for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install MDAC on Windows 10.  However, you probably dont need it.  Click `Start` and type "ODBC" and that will bring up `Setup ODBC Data Sources`.  There are 32 and 64 bit versions, you should probably use the 32 bit version.

Comment: @Ramhound ODBC wasnt integrated into the OS when MDAC came out

Comment: MDAC came out for Win9x. I think XP had it integrated, but required manual updates.

Comment: How does this help me with my vb6 projects?

Comment: why are you using 20 year old software?

Comment: My boss rejects change, I hate vb6

Comment: @Keltari Because in the real world very often there is no alternative or commercial justification to change.

Comment: Agreed with you, Alan.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this guide](http://blog.danbrust.net/2015/09/14/installing-visual-basic-studio-6-on-windows-10/#.Vu-QV2Zf1es).

RDO 2.0 can be taken form [here](http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/MSRdo20.cab) .

The file (MSRdo20.cab) is part of a cumulative updater for the vb6 sp6 runtime extended files.